# После слова "давайте" ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Давайте, не будем приносить боль матерям своими словами и поступками.
>   Мамы ждут от нас заботы, внимания, сочувствия и доброго слова. Давайте, будем
>   дарить своим мамам тепло даже в самый   хмурый день.

Comment: Я исправил: "перед" заменил на "после".

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, Вас интересует запятая ПОСЛЕ слова давайте?

Давайте не будем, давайте будем - это форма повелительного наклонения глагола быть, запятой после слова давайте нет.